# Is this Approach RESTful? [Server-Side Fields]

Tags: rest, server, resteasy, restful-architecture, application-server

Is it safe/correct to store values such as `int` or `String` on the server side via a private `List<>` array, in between API calls? For example, assume my server code has methods `methodA` & `methodB` where `methodA` simply computes the average of the two Integer parameters, returns the result, and adds the average into an array. Later on, if a user clicks a certain button ... `methodB` is called and returns the contents of that array.

```
 @Path("main/api")
    public class MainResource {

     private List <int> averageList = new List<>();

     @GET
     @Path("methodA/{val1}/{val2}")
     public Integer methodA(@PathParam("val1") final Integer val1,
                            @PathParam("val2") final Integer val2) {

      Integer average = (val1 + val2) / 2;
      averages.add(average);
      return average;
     }

    @GET
    @Path("methodB/")
    public List <Integer> methodB() {
     return averageList;
    }
   }
```

Can you explain why this does or does not violate RESTful design? I'm open to alternatives.

**Related:** I'm assuming that this approach is simply storing the array values into memory while it waits for the client to request it. Is this correct? In production code I'd of course add a database ... but for such small Integers and Strings, I wonder if server-side memory is sufficient/ideal for this?

---

### Update 1: RPC over HTTP

I've abandoned the `GET` method since the `POST` method alone can accept values via the JSON body and return the calculated average. Is this RESTful?

```
            @Path("main/api")
              public class MainResource {

                private List<Integer> averageList = new List<>();
                private Integer val1;
                private Integer val2;
                private Integer average;
                private Map<String, String> map;

                @POST
                @Path("methodA/")
                @Consumes("application/json")
                @Produces("application/json")
                  public Response performAverage(AverageData averageData) {
                    val1 = averageData.getVal1();
                    val2 = averageData.getVal2();

                    average = (val1 + val2) / 2;
                    averages.add(average);    //  <--- Modifies state
                    map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("Average: ", average);
                    return Response.ok(map).build();
                }
            }
```

**ClientDemo.java**

```
target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/NovaRest/rest/main/api/methodA");
String input = "{\"val1\":500,\"val2\":700}";
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(input, "application/json"));
String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("POST RESPONSE: " + value);
response.close();
```

Which correctly returns `{"Average: ":"600"}` .Obviously my production code is more complex and passes more variables which is why I 'm using a separate container class with only a no-argument constructor and a bunch of getters/setters. Is this now RESTful design?

Comment: what's the scope for those values? are they valid per application (for all users), or per user?

Comment: What HTTP verbs do you use for these calls? It would not be RESTful to make a `GET` request to `methodA` as you describe it, for example.

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu, I'm not sure how to determine the scope... they are `private` class variables, and are only usable by that server-side class (MainResource). My goal is to make this class valid for each user in the same way... I'm using the server to perform "sensitive" functions which I want to be guarded beyond the security provided by code obfuscators on the client side. Does this help? Sorry if I didn't answer your question

Comment: @LutzHorn, my code shows that I use `GET` for both methods, so I'm confused why you'd ask which verbs I use. Should I be using `PUT`/`POST` instead... if so, how would that look with my `List<>` ? I assume you're suggesting that I put/post those parameters into a database as opposed to letting them be maintained in memory? Any clarification/example would be excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `methodA` is not RESTful because it modifies state, `averageList` is changed. The state of your system will be different after every call to `methodA/{val1}/{val2}`, which is a violation of REST principles.

You should split *calculation* and *storing* of the average of two numbers into *two* REST resources.

- `GET /main/api/average/{val1}/{val2}` would calculate the average and do nothing else. The server state must not be changed.
- `POST /main/api/averages` with a number in the body would append the number to `averageList`.

Comment: Thanks Lutz, would it be acceptable to remove the `GET` request altogether in this context and just use `POST`? Since `POST` is not idempotent or safe, that means I can use it to alter the resource state, so can't I simply pass `val1` and `val2` via the JSON body and have the post method return the average that was calculated with those values? I have updated my question to reflect the changes I've made. It uses a separate class to store values... and seems to work, but is it RESTful now?

Comment: This would not be a direct violation of REST principles. But it would still not be RESTful, it would be RPC over HTTP. If you want to do REST, you should first think about what your Resources are.